# Matplotlib: Identify bars in bar plot based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

The code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [['Apple',10],['Banana',15],['Kiwi',11],['Orange',17]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Fruit','Quantity'])
df.set_index('Fruit', inplace=True)
df.plot.bar(color='gray',rot=0)
plt.show()
```

gives the following output:

[image]

I would like to plot bars in red color for the top two quantity fruits i.e., Orange and Banana. How can I do that? Instead of giving a fixed threshold value to change color, I would prefer if my plot is robust enough to identify top two bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a straightforward and simpler way but I was able to come up with the following solution which would work in principle for any number of top `n` values. The idea is:

- First get the top `n` elements (`n=2` in the example below) from the DataFrame using `nlargest`
- Then, loop over the x-tick labels and change the color of the patches (bars) for those values which are the largest using an `if` statement to get their index. Here we created an axis instance `ax` to be able to extract the patches for setting the colors.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = [['Apple',10],['Banana',15],['Kiwi',11],['Orange',17]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Fruit','Quantity'])

df.set_index('Fruit', inplace=True)
df.plot.bar(color='gray',rot=0, ax=ax)

top = df['Quantity'].nlargest(2).keys() # Top 2 values here

for i, tick in enumerate(ax.get_xticklabels()):
    if tick.get_text() in top:
        ax.patches[i].set_color('r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Plotting a colored bar plot

The problem is that pandas bar plots take the `color` argument to apply column-wise. Here you have a single column. Hence something like the canonical attempt to color a bar plot does **not** work

```
pd.DataFrame([12,14]).plot.bar(color=["red", "green"])
```

A workaround is to create a diagonal matrix instead of a single column and plot it with the `stacked=True` option.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([12,14])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(df[0].values), index=df.index, columns=df.index)
df.plot.bar(color=["red", "green"], stacked=True)
```

Another option is to use matplotlib instead.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([12,14])
plt.bar(df.index, df[0].values, color=color)
```

#### Choosing the colors according to values

Now the question remains on how to create a list of the colors to use in either of the two solutions above. Given a dataframe `df` you can create an array of equal length to the frame and fill it with the default color, then you can set those entries of the two highest values to another color:

```
color = np.array(["gray"]*len(df))
color[np.argsort(df["Quantity"])[-2:]] = "red"
```

#### Solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [['Apple',10],['Banana',15],['Kiwi',11],['Orange',17]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Fruit','Quantity'])
df.set_index('Fruit', inplace=True)

color = np.array(["gray"]*len(df))
color[np.argsort(df["Quantity"])[-2:]] = "red"

plt.bar(df.index, df.values, color=color)

plt.show()
```

[image]